# 301 Redirect on nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect

I'm doing a 301 redirect from old domains to the new domain but can't able to exactly make it work.

So just a TLD change and everything else is same.. Like URL

Old domain : https://donateers.com
New domain https://donateers.org

Here is the code I tried in the nginx file but got 503 error.

```
server {
    . . .
    server_name donateers.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://donateers.org/$1 permanent;
    . . .
}
```

The site is using the easy engine stack

Thanks
Suresh

Comment: Try `return 301 https://donateers.org$request_uri;`

Comment: The error seems to be unrelated to the configuration statements in your question. What do you see in the access and error logs? Does the configuration pass the `nginx -t` test? Use `curl -I` to verify that the redirect is occurring correctly.

Comment: Return didn't helped...but at the last I used the rewrite only at the main.conf file. 

And that worked. I guess, previously I was adding the code at different nginx file.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

The above code works, Just I need to add in the main.conf file

Just below the code of

```
server_name donateers.com;
```

I need to add the following 1 line of code to do the 301 redirect.

```
rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://donateers.org/$1 permanent;
```

We're making the redirection permanent here and every URL of old domain change to the new URL with 301 redirection. Even works with http, www version of donateers.com

After you add this.. You need to restart the start with the one line of command.

```
ee site restart donateers.com
```

EasyEngine makes it very handy.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443;
        server_name  .donateers.com;

        return 301 $scheme://donateers.org$request_uri;
}
```